# Select a folder by creation date

Tags: cmd

Is it possible to select the most recent folder `.PhpStorm*` by creation date?

My command is:

```
cd /d "%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.PhpStorm*\config"
```

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using the `dir` command. This command allows for the ability to list folders by date created. Using this, we can have it sort all folders by the name `PhpStorm` and use a basic `Set` command to keep setting a new output path for each folder found. Since the "Latest" folder will always be last, the final string will be the path to the "Latest" folder. From here the basic `CD` command can be used.

The command `DIR` has many switches. The ones we are using is listed bellow or [here on microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir):

- `/A:D` - Displays only Directories.
- `/T:C` - Specifies which time field to display **->** Our case Creation.
- `/O:D` - Sorts the output according to date.

**Batch Script:**

```
Rem | Base Path & Folder Name
Set "BasePath=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
Set "FolderName=PhpStorm"

Rem | Search & Sort All Folders By Creation
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('dir "%BasePath%\%FolderName%.*" /A:D /T:C /O:D /S^| find /i "Directory"^| find /v "<DIR>"') do (

    Rem | Set Each Result; Last Result Will be Latest Created Folder
    Set "Latest=%%b"
)

Rem | CD To Directory/Drive
CD /D "%Latest%\config"

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have corrected some mistakes. But I have a problem with the variable "Latest" there is Date and time in Variable %%i -> c:\>CD /D 11/24/2018  04:41 PM     0<DIR 1>.PhpStorm2018.3\config
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: John forgot another needed `dir` switch: `/b` - **b**are format (name only, no size or date) Just add it to the `dir` switches and delete the `/s` (for subfolders - you don't want them) and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code and screenshot

```
Rem | Base Path & Folder Name
Set "BasePath=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%"
Set "FolderName=.PhpStorm"

Rem | Search & Sort All Folders By Creation
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir "%BasePath%\%FolderName%*" /A:D /T:C /O:D /S^| find /i "PhpStorm"') do (

    Rem | Set Each Result; Last Result Will be Latest Created Folder
    Set "Latest=%%i"
)

Rem | CD To Directory/Drive
CD /D %Latest%\config

GOTO :EOF
```

[Script execution result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9y3x.png)